# How to have a list that contains the 10 most recent values of an iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to have a list that contains the ten most recent values as calculated in a `for` loop.
I tried to remove the `i - 10` element of the list and then append the value calculated in the `i'th` iteration. Here is what I tried:

```
points = []

x = 0
for i in range(1000):
    x += 1

    if i > 9: # to check when to start removing the first element
        del points[i - 10]
        points.append(i * x * (1 - x)) # appending the value calculating
    else:
        points.append(i * x * (1 - x))
```

However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*******.py", line 9, in <module>
    del points[i - 10]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I'm not sure why this is, as the list is long enough, assured by the condition.
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: If you put `print(i)` in the loop you would see clearly that it fails when `i` = 20, and would probably have been able to work out what is going wrong.

Comment: @alaniwi you're right, thank you

Comment: Built-in collections module includes [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects) which can used just `points = deque(maxlen=10)` and subsequent appending.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your list never grows longer than 10 elements, because as soon as it gets to length 10, you start deleting the first element before you add one. Therefore, when `i` is greater than 19, the index `i - 10` is out of range for the list.

You are always adding to the end of the list, and logically only ever want to remove the *first* element. Therefore, replace the `del points[i - 10]` by `del points[0]`:

```
points = []

x = 0
for i in range(1000):
    x += 1

    if i > 9: # to check when to start removing the first element
        del points[0]
        points.append(i * x * (1 - x)) # appending the value calculating
    else:
        points.append(i * x * (1 - x))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start by creating a list of length 10 and then just cycle through the indices. To extract the values you'll have to extract the slices from `index + 1` to the end and then from the start to `index` (where `index` is the current index of the points list, i.e. `i % 10`).

This will be much more efficient than modifying a list, as removing the first element of a list have time complexity O(n).

```
points = [None] * 10

for i in range(1000):
    x = i + 1  # This seems to be the same as your x.
    value = i * x * (1 - x)

    index = i % 10
    points[index] = value

    # Do this whenever you want to print
    index = (index + 1) % 10
    print('Recent values:', points[index:] + points[:index])
```

If you want the output on without `None` and have the elements ordered from newest to oldest, you could print them like this instead:

```
ordered_filtered_list = [x for x in (points[index:] + points[:index]) if x is not None]
print('Recent values:', ordered_filtered_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Think about what happens when `i` is 100: you're trying to delete the element in `points[90]` but your list only has length of 10 hence the out of range error. Really you'd like to delete the first element of the list every time. So that line should read `del points[0]`.

However, a much more efficient way of doing this is to use [slicing](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/) to always ensure the list is no more than 10 long:

```py
points = []

for i in range(1000):
    x = i+1
    points.append(i * x * (1 - x))
    points = points[-10:]
```

`points[-10:]` selects all elements from the 10th last element in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you have an index out of range!  You're keeping only 10 items in the list, but `i` ranges up to 999!  If there are only 10 items in the list, how do you imagine that you can index item `998 - 10`?

You need to imagine this as a queue: a data structure in which you take items off the front and add them to the end.  In fact, the `Collections` package has such a data structure.  For your own purposes, however, simly do what you *said* you were going to do: get rid of the oldest item:

```
if i > 9: # to check when to start removing the first element
    points.pop(0)

points.append(i * x * (1 - x))
```

Note that I've refactored your new element: you do the same thing in each branch of the `if`, so there's no sense in duplicating the code.

Your final `points` is

```
[-971279100, -974224352, -977175552, -980132706, -983095820,
 -986064900, -989039952, -992020982, -995007996, -998001000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `del points[i - 10]` to `del points[0]` as when i reaches 20 it tries to delete index 10 which does not exist. So just change it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
points = []

x = 0
for i in range(1000):
    x += 1

    if i > 9: # to check when to start removing the first element
        del points[0]
        points.append(i * x * (1 - x)) # appending the value calculating
    else:
        points.append(i * x * (1 - x))
```

This works because once you get to 10 elements in the list you are only adding one element at a time and you will always be deleting the first element of the list, i.e. points[0]

Comment: What does this add to the previous answers?

Comment: @Prune, regardless of whether it adds something or not, it helps me understand the solution in different perspectives, and as the person asking the question, this is very helpful to me.

Comment: @Prune, sorry, my answer crossed the other one in the ether.